# mapbox how to round angles of popup

Tags: css, popup, mapbox

Is it possible with mapbox to round the angles of the popup i tried to put a border radius in the css but it does not work, thank you in advance for your help !!

```css
.mapboxgl.popup {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: orange;
  border-style: solid;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  max-height: 400px;
  padding:4px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 8px;   
  padding:0; 
 border-radius: 30px;
   border-color: orange;

}
```

```js
    var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({color:'orange'}) // Initialize a new marker
  .setLngLat([5.45,45.545]) // Marker [lng, lat] coordinates
  .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup() 
  .setHTML('<p><b><h2><font color="orange">1</font><img src="/img/pers1.png" width="20" height="25"/></h2> <font color="black">Alderaan droid calrissian luuke zabrak coruscant jango. Jade yoda gonk sebulba.</b></p>')
  .setMaxWidth(600))
  .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css code works for me... Not sure what's the expected result you are looking for but just copying and pasting your css into my custom css, it works. Are you sure you're adding this css stylesheed AFTER the css of mapbox??

```html
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/YOUR_CUSTOM_FOLDER/YOUR_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I add my links, thank you to help me jscastro..

Answer (score 0):

I add  !important to border-radius, it works!

Comment: It should work without !important if the order of the cascade is right. Anyway, good you solved it

Answer (score 0):

After hours searching for what the friend said, it worked for me. In angular I did everything and I couldn't modify it, so I created a style sheet and linked it to the index.html that angular brings (not the pages we created but the index.html as such, where libraries are added and that, after the mapbox css library) works now I can modify everything to taste

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a css style sheet.
2. Whether it's with angular or another framework, try to always after the mapbox.css
3. add the index.html of your angular/ionic
4. Modify to your liking in that sheet, not in the scss of the pages that you create.